# Acceder a un campo dentro de un dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo un fichero con extensión `.txt` el cual representa un dataframe. Dicho df incluye tres columnas. Una columna con un campo llamado "ingresos", que recoge los ingresos de un determinado país, otra columna con los datos de desempleo llamada "desp" y una última llamada "continente", que recoge el continente al que pertence un determinado país. En la columna continente se incluyen todos los continentes del mundo.

**-->** Continente es una columna del df que cuenta con 105 elementos, por tanto, el df tiene 105 filas. Los elementos del campo "continente se distribuyen de la siguiente forma:

```
Continente
Asia
Europa
Europa
Africa
Ameria
Asia
Africa
Asia
.
.
.
```

A partir de dicho df, necesito obtener la media y desviación estándar, **analizando los ingresos de los paises y la tasa de desempleo en función del continente**. Para ello, he tratado lo siguiente:

```
media_ingresos <- mean(continente$ingresos)
media_ingresos

sd_ingresos <- sd(continente$ingresos)
sd_ingresos

media_desempleo <- mean(continente$desp)
media_desempleo

sd_desempleo <- sd(continente$desp)
sd_desempleo
```

El problema del código es que me devuelve `Error in continente$ingresos : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

También he buscado si dichas operaciones se pueden realizar de la forma `media_ingresos_desp <- mean(continente$ingresos$desp)`
ya que me piden **analizando los ingresos de los paises y la tasa de desempleo en función del continente calcular la media y la desviación esándar**

Comment: ¿`continente` es un `data.frame` o es una columna del mismo? agrega la salida de `str(continente)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> Error in continente$ingresos : $ operator is invalid for atomic
> vectors

Lo que te está explicando es que no podes usar el operador `$` para acceder a los elementos de un `vector`, y es así por que dicho operador solo funciona sobre elementos tipo `list`, por ejemplo un `data.frame`. Pareciera que estás trabajando con las columnas "desenganchadas" del `data.frame`.

Si tienes algo como esto (uso el paquete `gapminer`, por los datos se parecen a tu ejemplo):

```
library(gapminder)

df <- as.data.frame(gapminder[gapminder$year==2002, c('country', 'continent', 'gdpPercap')])
head(df)

      country continent  gdpPercap
1 Afghanistan      Asia   726.7341
2     Albania    Europe  4604.2117
3     Algeria    Africa  5288.0404
4      Angola    Africa  2773.2873
5   Argentina  Americas  8797.6407
6   Australia   Oceania 30687.7547
```

Para obtener, la media y desviación estándar por continente, es necesario agrupar las observaciones, con R base puedes hacerlo así:

```
aggregate(gdpPercap ~ continent, 
          df, 
          FUN = function(x) c(media = mean(x), std = sd(x))
)

  continent gdpPercap.media gdpPercap.stdn
1    Africa        2599.385       2972.651
2  Americas        9287.677       8895.818
3      Asia       10174.090      11150.719
4    Europe       21711.732      11197.356
5   Oceania       26938.778       5301.854
```